A little wish for you
What can I say? Everything you need to know is in the following image:


We can first solve the clues:

   Note: the first clue as presented resolves to TKL WINE, but I believe there should be an extra H for reasons which will become apparent below

Then, note that

 Each clue resolves to a word from Twinkle Twinkle Little Star, with an extra letter:

Finally,

 The extra letters spell out Lezzup's wish for us: a HAPPY AND HEALTHY NEW YEAR!


Ouch! As a non-native speaker, I saw "whine" as a valid word, and I even googled it to get an image. And nobody at google warned me, they just showed me lots of pictures of wine. (facepalm). Sorry, but good solve nonetheless!
